# pushing a new remote branch gives error committer e-mail address does not match

Tags: git

With a command similar to

```
git checkout -b a7e4767 new-branch
git push origin new-branch
```

I get the following error

```
remote: ERROR:  In commit a7e4767a80e9b0730c8708973918c990af308a45        
remote: ERROR:  committer email address someone.else@xyz.com        
remote: ERROR:  does not match your user account.        
remote: ERROR:        
remote: ERROR:  The following addresses are currently registered:        
remote: ERROR:    my.self@sap.com
```

All my search turns up suggestions for amending the commit, but I don't think I want to amend that old commit.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a `git` issue, strictly speaking. This sounds more like a webhook. What service are you using... GitHub, BitBucket, GitLab? Any custom hooks?

Comment: @JDB It's my corporate git server, and I am sure there are custom hooks but I don't know what they are. Can you explain why you don't think it is git issue, that will help me ask a more intelligent question to corporate support (they are not always as tolerant as SO :) )

Comment: Anything prefixed with `remote:` is coming from the other Git involved in the push, but if it comes *directly* from that Git, it does not get the `remote:` prefix. So it therefore must be from a hook. It's pretty standard, in corporate environments, to check for misconfiguration or spoofing, depending on how much trust their is from management down to lower level employees... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a git issue, strictly speaking. This sounds more like a [feature offered by Gerrit](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-invalid-committer.html)

If you are registered with the system and your email address is setup correctly in your local repo, then you might be able to layer over a new commit with no changes and push that. The new commit will be tagged with your email address, which gets around the need to modify the existing commit. See [How to commit no change and new message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470029/how-to-commit-no-change-and-new-message)

I think the proper way to handle this situation, however, would be to [get the "Forge Committer" permission](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_forge_committer).

Comment: I don't want to create a new commit either. I just want to create a remote branch that points to a commit by someone else

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you are going to need the "Forge Committer" permission.

Comment: I doubt.  This worked: (1) `git checkout some-existing-remote-branch` (2) `git checkout -b new-branch` (3) `git push origin new-brach`. But it did not work when (1) was replaced by (1) `git checkout some-existing-label`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error when our corporate  email address changed and for me was easily fixed with :

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Run in the root of the git repo.

Based on : 
https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-author-info

I also edited the repo's .git/config to add the user stanza :

```
[user]
  name = Your Correct Name
  email = your-correct-email@example.com
```

Then

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
git push
```

PS: This is on a Gerrit Server